# Can I add a special character ñ in my domain on heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, special-characters

I'm trying to add my domain to my heroku app.

I run:

```
heroku domains:add www.urlwithanñ.com
```

and I get the message: "Domain is invalid"

¿Is this because of the ñ ?

I have successfully registered the domain so it can't be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs with special characters like ñ need to be encoded into Punycode.

A nice tool for this is http://punycoder.com/ There are many others on the web.

In Heroku you need to add your Punyencoded url.

Eg: For www.derosecerviño.com.ar you'll need to add www.xn--derosecervio-khb.com.ar instead.

Answer (score 3):

DNS doesn't natively support non-ASCII characters, but recent efforts in [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) provided a way to map non-ASCII characters into characters that DNS supports. Because of [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode), while the receipt says you bought `urlwithanñ.com`, as far as the machines are concerned, you actually own `xn--urlwithan-t6a.com`.

Try `heroku domains:add www.xn--urlwithan-t6a.com`.